# Usage of Floquet's Method

Tags: differential-equations, stability, complex-systems, floquet-theory

I'm treating with a nonlinear system of ODE, in which one of my fixed points is non-hyperbolic, that is,  its eigenvalues has ($\Re(\lambda_{1,2}) = 0$). Therefore, I cannot say anything about its stability from the linear analysis once it does not satisfy [Hartman-Grobman theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartman%E2%80%93Grobman_theorem). To overcome this difficulty I want to use [Floquet's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floquet_theory) to define the stability of the closed orbit, but apparently this should be used for linear systems. My doubt is: Can I use Floquet's method in the linerized system? If not, is there any nonlinear kind of Floquet's treatment?